# Connect Sonarqube to MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sonarqube

I have a Sonarqube installation which connects to a SQL Server database. This has been configured and working for close to 12 months.

Today I upgraded Sonar, from an old version (3.x) to the current stable 5.1

I am getting an error like:

```
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: 
                   org.sonar.process.MessageException: 
                   Unsupported JDBC driver provider: sqlserver
jvm 1    | org.sonar.process.MessageException: Unsupported JDBC driver provider:
                   sqlserver
```

I specified the path to the mssql jar in the `conf` file, so can't see any reason why this is occurring. Has anyone come across this, or any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Support for SQL Server is achieved using the [jTDS driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) that is bundled with SonarQube, and this can't be changed since SQ 4.5 (see [SONAR-5499](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5499)).

So if your remove the specific entry that you set in the `conf/sonar.properties` file to specify the path to your JDBC driver, this should solve the problem.